Flutter foreground and background location fetching in iOS?
I need to fetch the location in foreground and background in IOS Fluter.
I used the package background_location but it only work once, not recurring the process.
Future<void> checkAndRequestLocationPermission() async {
// Check the current location permission status
LocationPermission permission = await Geolocator.checkPermission();

// If permission is denied, request permission
if (permission == LocationPermission.denied) {
  permission = await Geolocator.requestPermission();
}

// Handle permanently denied permissions
if (permission == LocationPermission.deniedForever) {
  // Show a dialog or message to the user indicating that they need to enable location permissions in settings
  print(
      'Location permissions are permanently denied. Please enable them in settings.');
} else if (permission == LocationPermission.whileInUse ||
    permission == LocationPermission.always) {
  // Permission granted, proceed with location access
  print('Location permission granted.');
  if (Platform.isAndroid) {
    await BackgroundLocation.setAndroidNotification(
      title: "Notification title",
      message: "Notification message",
      icon: "@mipmap/ic_launcher",
    );

    await BackgroundLocation.setAndroidConfiguration(1000);
  }

  await BackgroundLocation.startLocationService(distanceFilter: 10)
      .then((e) {
    print(e.toString());
  });

  BackgroundLocation.getLocationUpdates((location) {
    print(location);
  });
} else {
  // Handle other cases if needed
  print('Location permission status: $permission');
}

}
Any idea, How to solve this.

Have you received and responded to the dialog asking you to grant your app "always" location permission?  The initial request will only be for "while in use" permission. The upgrade request will come after your app has used location in the background for some time

The permission is given always

I don't see any issues with the code itself; the problem might be due to poor implementation on iOS, such as not handling battery consumption cases properly. Since it hasn't been updated for 5 months, I recommend trying a more recently updated, well documented and popular package, like flutter_background_geolocation.
